# docker migration of containers from one subnet to another

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, dns, traefik

Hello I would need to explain following situation in docker world.

I have several containers in a subnet network with Primary DNS server (can be default docker DNS server). I need to create containers in another subnet network with different Primary DNS server and with minimal downtime.

I created new docker network and custom Bind9 DNS server in docker. I created DNS record and I created container with flag  --ip=172.30.0.3 --dns=172.30.0.2 and --ip=172.30.0.4 --dns=172.30.0.2

DNS record contains lines with domain names and ip addresses above.

My question: How can I created loadbalancer (or any other solution) that will split traffic to old containers and to new ones ?  My idea was to create nginx load balancer that will split traffic between old containes and new ones and I will configure domain names for new containers